# login to the application using facebook account

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I am connecting to facebook from my application using "https://ssl.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" Now its not working. When i make it http its working fine. what is the reason for this? How to make it work with https. is facebook changed the url... here is my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old featureloader JS SDK is deprecated and i thought was already removed - if it's still working, you should stop using it immediately and look at the current SDK and documentation to see how to implement login.

For a start, the method of including the [current JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: @lgy. how to get this appid. Is there any process fro this?

Comment: Presumably you already have one if you have an app - developers.facebook.com/apps lists your apps

Comment: The javascript SDK? no, you'll need to make changes to your code to use the current SDK